# Существует ли система массового управления софтом для Android?

Tags: android, поиск-программ

Подскажите существует ли не сильно платные или OpenSource проекты по управлению софтом Android ?
Что-то вроде Ansible для Android?
Имеется какое-то количество устройств, на которых периодически приходится обновлять ПО или докатывать что-то, а руками делать сильно больно и долго.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует Open-Source платформа для управления корпоративными Android-устройствами [Headwind MDM](https://h-mdm.com/ru/home/).

Comment: Ответы-ссылки запрещены правилами сайта :)

Comment: @andreymal, надо было всего лишь немного подправить ответ.